# Can I create dynamic subdomains with .htaccess?

Tags: htaccess, subdomain

I want to create dynamic subdomains using only a .htaccess file. For example:

```
http://site.asd/user.php?name=jon > http://jon.site.asd/
http://site.asd/user.php?name=username > http://username.site.asd/
```

How can I set up my .htaccess to redirect like this?

Comment: "Only htaccess" won't do this; your DNS and web server need to be specifically configured for this.

Comment: Do realize that when you create a subdomain that some time must pass before the subdomain is accessible to the world. If you're trying to make URLs for each user on your site, then you're better off using subfolders. For example: `http://site.asd/username/whatever` and `http://site.asd/jon/whatever`

Comment: @Mike That's nonsense. If you configure sub domains via wild cards, there's no time delay at all, because you don't need to change any configuration for a new sub domain in the first place. Even if you actually add a new sub domain configuration each time, it is available immediately; only clients which may have cached an old DNS query before the domain existed are bound to their cache expiration, but why would somebody query a non-existent domain?

Comment: If the OP plans to use subdomains as way of identifying users, its very possible that a guest would type an incorrect subdomain. For example, if a valid user on the system is Rick and the guest thinks Jake exists, but it does not, the guest would type in "jake.example.com" which doesn't exist, but "rick.example.com" exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without using .htaccess at all. What you need to do is define a [wildcard DNS record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) directing all queries on the subdomains to your application server. The using whatever language you are developing in you would check the host header (fully qualified domain name) to identify the user being requested. Then as part of your application code if the user exists do what you need to, if the user does not exist return an error saying that the user does not exist.

NB: This is very much how [GitHub Pages](https://help.github.com/pages/) works.